# Add flag for row existence in another table with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, boolean-logic

For below query I want to have a flag called `isHold` that will evaluate to 0
if there is no `billNo` from the view `viewBills` exists in `onHold` table and
1 otherwise

```
select max(t.id) TrackingID , max(vb.billNo) billNo, cb.id  ,
max(case when vb.[count] > 1 then 1 else 0 end) isMultiple ,
max(case when t.TrackingID = 31 then 1 else 0 end) IsCancelled,
max(case when exists (select 1 from OnHold oh
where oh.billNo = billNo) then 1 else 0 end) IsHold

from viewBills vb
join tracking t on vb.billNo = t.billNo
join customerBills cb on vb.billNo = cb.billNo 
join customerPieces cp on  cb.id = cp.customerBillId
where cb.statusid <> 3
group by cb.id
```

I got this error when executing

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression 
containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

It's reasonable but how can achieve that?

Comment: You have `cb.id` in the `select`, but `cp.id` in the `group by`.

Comment: Actually that's a typo

Comment: You can move it into a `outer apply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outer apply` or a `left join` to move the logic to the `FROM` clause:

```
select max(t.id) as TrackingID , max(vb.billNo) as billNo, cb.id ,
       max(case when vb.[count] > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as isMultiple,
       max(case when t.TrackingID = 31 then 1 else 0 end) as IsCancelled,
       max(case when oh.billNo is not null then 1 else 0 end) as IsHold
from viewBills vb join
     tracking t
     on vb.billNo = t.billNo join
     customerBills cb
     on vb.billNo = cb.billNo  join
     customerPieces cp
     on cb.id = cp.customerBillId outer apply
     (select top (1) oh.*
      from OnHold oh
      where oh.billNo = cb.billNo
     ) oh
where cw.statusid <> 3
group by cb.id;
```

Comment: How can I do it using left join?

Comment: @Alvaro . . . I prefer `outer apply` to `left join`, which is why I use this method.

Comment: May I know why? is it more efficient?

Comment: @Alvaro . . . It chooses only one row, so the aggregation does not have to do as much work if there are multiple possible matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for LEFT OUTER JOIN and do the aggregation as given below:

```sql
select max(t.id) TrackingID , max(vb.billNo) billNo, cb.id  ,
max(case when vb.[count] > 1 then 1 else 0 end) isMultiple ,
max(case when t.TrackingID = 31 then 1 else 0 end) IsCancelled,
max(case when oh.billNo IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) IsHold

from viewBills vb
join tracking t on vb.billNo = t.billNo
join customerBills cb on vb.billNo = cb.billNo 
join customerPieces cp on  cb.id = cp.customerBillId
LEFT OUTER JOIN OnHold oh ON oh.billNo = vb.billNo
where cb.statusid <> 3
group by cb.id
```